# Django allow deletion of inline objects in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models. One is displayed as inline from admin view. For the model inline I can set a tick on the delete, but there is no button allowing me to delete the model object.

In my models.py

```
class deliveryRegion(models.Model):
    deliveryRegionName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deliveryRegionActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    regions = models.ManyToManyField(Regions)
    circularDeliveryDateActive = models.BooleanField(
        help_text='Activates the running day. For example offering delivery every Tuesday every third week for the next 4 weeks',
        default = False)
    circularDeliveryDeliveryWeekDay = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = days, blank = True)
    circularDeliveryStartingFromDay = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    circularDeliveryEveryWeek = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 1,
    help_text='The delivery week day will be repeated every x weeks',
    blank = True)

    selfPreDefinedDeliveryDateActive = models.BooleanField(
        help_text='Predefined delivery date. When this method is active, then circularDeliveryDateActive button must be switched off!',
        default = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['deliveryRegionName']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.deliveryRegionName

class DeliveryDate(models.Model):
    deliveryDate = models.DateField()
    deliveryRegion = models.ForeignKey(deliveryRegion, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='deliveryRegion')
```

In admin.py I have set the `DeliveryDate` model inline in the `deliveryRegion` model. My intension is upon creating the `deliveryRegion` model object in the admin, I should be able to add a `DeliveryDate` model object.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import deliveryRegion, DeliveryDate
from .forms import deliveryRegionForm

# Register your models here.

class DeliveryDateInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DeliveryDate
admin.site.register(DeliveryDate)

class deliveryRegionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = deliveryRegionForm
    inlines = [DeliveryDateInline]

    class Meta:
        model = deliveryRegion

admin.site.register(deliveryRegion, deliveryRegionAdmin)
```

In the admin view under the deliveryRegion model, I can put a delete tick on each DeliveryDate model object, but there is no way to actually delete them directly from that view.
[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to click "SAVE".

Comment: Nope, clicking on "Save" does not do it, and I couldn't find any other way.

Comment: Then you have something preventing it, I do it all day long and always works. Use a debugger to follow through the execution path.